# my task is to print a string inside a frame for example a square

Tags: c++, string, loops, nested, nested-loops

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i=1,len;
    char ch[26][26],ch2;
    cout<<"enter string: "<<endl;   
    for(i=0;;i++)
    {
        cin>>ch[i];
        len++;
        if(getchar()=='\n')
        break;
    }
    int n,j;
    cout<<"enter size: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    int k;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=n;j++)
        {
            if(i==0||i==n||j==0||j==n)
            {
                cout<<"*";
            }
            else
                cout<<" ";
            if(i==((n/2)-2)&&j==((n/2)-2))
            {
                for(k=0;k<len;k++)
                {
                    cout<<ch[k]<<endl;
                    cout<<"*";
                }
            }
        }   
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```

this program is displaying string inside the square but the star pattern of squares is getting messed up espeacially the right most column
ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED

Comment: If you look at your code which is printing the string, notice you start printing the string in the middle of the square, but you are not considering the length of the string that you are supposed to print. You need to compute where the middle is in relation to the string. Also, I would recommend actually using the [string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) class instead of a char array and then you can use [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read it in.

Comment: the star is not printing after each word which is messing up the right most column

Comment: could you edit your question to explain where exactly is the issue? And what is the expected output? Add examples!

Comment: yep, can you add some please? It would greatly help figure out your problem

Comment: THE ISSUE IS IN THE LOOP WHERE I AM PRINTING THE STRING THE WORDS ARE BEING PRINTED BUT AFTERWARDS THE STARS ARE NOT BEING PRINTED

Comment: Please do not shout

Comment: sorry i didnt noticed that the caps lock was open

Comment: I ran your code before making my statement. The star IS printing after the word, just not in the way you want. Please re-read my statement regarding the length of the word and the size of the square, you are starting the printing in the middle of the square rather than computing the center point for the word.

Comment: Sorry, computer locked up and took to long to be able to edit previous comment. I was trying to push you in the correct direction for an answer as I am assuming this is some kind of homework problem. The star IS printing after each word and you are adding a newline after each word, so it IS printing, but it is not printing in the way that you are wanting it to print, and since you have not provided a more detailed description of WHAT you intend, we are all just inferring what it is you want.

Comment: I hope you've got food for thought! If you're satisfied with an answer, can you accept it? (definitely not craving for rep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not provide much details in your code, I started from the beginnig with a new code and this is what I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
```

Use a vector for your strings, with dynamic resizing (what if, in your code, I enter more than 26 words? Hint: *segmentation fault*!)

```
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
```

Using `using namespace std;` is best avoided. Just import what you really need.

```
int main() {
    vector<string> strings;
```

You definitely want to use strings here, not `char` arrays.

```
    cout << "Enter string: ";
```

Do not break line after an input prompt! (as a Linux user, I personnaly hate it)

```
    for(;;) {
```

You do not need the variable `i` here, just run an infinite loop (try to rearrange that, once again if you can avoid infinite loops, a `while(getchar() != '\n')` is more self-explanatory.

```
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        strings.push_back(s);
```

As *pstrjds* suggested in a comment, use `getline()` if you can.

```
        if(getchar() == '\n')
            break;
```

Like I said, try to reformulate with a `while` condition.

```
    }
    unsigned int n, i, j;
    cout << "Enter size: ";
    cin >> n;

    // assuming strings.size() < n
    unsigned int empty_lines_around_text((n - strings.size()) / 2);
```

Since you want to print your words centered inside your square, you have to display less than half a square of `* (...)  *` lines: actually half a square *minus* half the number of strings to print.

```
    // first horizontal row of stars
    for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        cout << '*';
    cout << endl;
```

The upper side of the square.

```
    for(i = 1; i < empty_lines_around_text; ++i) {
        cout << '*';
        for(j = 1; j < n - 1; ++j) {
            cout << ' ';
        }
        cout << '*' << endl;
    }
```

The first lines to print, those without string inside them.

```
    //here we do the actual printing of the strings
    for(i = 0; i < strings.size(); ++i) {
        string s = strings[i];

        // once again, assuming the size of each string is < n
        unsigned int empty_chars_around_string((n - s.size()) / 2);
        cout << '*';
        for(j = 0; j < empty_chars_around_string; ++j)
            cout << ' ';
        cout << s;
        for(j = empty_chars_around_string + s.size() + 1; j < n - 1; ++j)
            cout << ' ';
        cout << '*' << endl;
    }
```

This is the problematic part. Like for the empty lines, we need a variable to contain how much spaces we have to print before the string so that it appears centered (variable *empty_chars_around_string*).
We print that much spaces, the string, and we complete the line with spaces before the line-ending `*`, and this for each string in the array.

```
    for(i = empty_lines_around_text + strings.size() + 1; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << '*';
        for(j = 1; j < n - 1; ++j) {
            cout << ' ';
        }
        cout << '*' << endl;
    }
```

We complete the square with empty lines, after the strings have been printed.

```
    // last horizontal line of '*' (we close the square)
    for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        cout << '*';
    cout << endl;
```

...Aaand we close the square.

```
return 0;
}
```

Now, this code is not perfect, there is a bunch of refactoring and optimizing to do, but it maximizes the use of C++ features.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/m0Q4pazT) is a PasteBin with the whole code.

The output, when ran with the strings `Hello friends` and size `12`:

```
************
*          *
*          *
*          *
*          *
*   hello  *
*  friends *
*          *
*          *
*          *
*          *
************
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem lies at:

```
for(k=0;k<len;k++)
{
    cout<<ch[k]<<endl;
    cout<<"*";
}
```

Here when you come to place the input string, you also enter a new line and start with an asterisk (*). Not only you don't put the last asterisk on the input string's line, but you also don't update *j* there, it's still greater than 0 and when the code continues with `for(j=0;j<=n;j++)` j already has the leftover value from the newline + asterisk.

Try:

```
for( k = 0; k<len; k++ )
{
    cout << ch[k];
    j += strlen( ch[k] );
}
```

This way *j* will update to the last position of the input string.

PS: For common coding practise initialize *len* in the beginning to 0 as well.

Comment: i love stack overflow and thanks everyone you all are saviour